# How to choose operational amplifier for 4th order bandpass filter in inductive pickup setup?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I would like to measure the 3rd harmonic at 15 kHz of a sample that is subjected to a 5 kHz magnetic field generated by an electromagnet. For this purpose, the circuit shown below consisting of a LT1115 based preamplifier and a 4th order bandpass is used. The output of this circuit should eventually be fed into a tabletop lock-in amplifier.

[image]

For the preamplifier I decided to use a LT1115 mostly because of its low input noise. I expect the 3rd harmonic of the sample to induce a voltage of approx. 120 nVrms in the pickup coil and the LT1115 offers below 1 \$\text{nV}/\sqrt{\text{Hz}}\$ above 1 kHz according to the datasheet.

I am not so sure what op amp I should use for the secondary 4th order bandpass stage. The goal of this stage is to amplify the 15 kHz signal generated by the sample while rejecting (or amplifying much less) the 5 kHz background field generated by the electromagnet. The amplification at 5 kHz is around 60 dB lower than the amplification at 15 kHz.

The criterion that comes to mind would the linearity of the amplifier. At the input of the bandpass I will still have a 5 kHz component that could be 60 dB stronger than the 15 kHz component I want to measure. So if the amplifier generates itself harmonics that might be an issue.

Comment: Use a simulator and use decent op-amp models.

Comment: Consider a passive notch, or at least a high pass filter, between stages to remove/attenuate 5 kHz if you're worried about 2nd stage distortion.

Comment: If you have an electromagnet generating a 5 kHz field, you might find the distortion of the magnet itself exceeds the sample distortion, unless it's air cored with nothing ferrous in its vicinity.

Comment: *The criterion that comes to mind would the linearity of the amplifier.* Then "put some numbers on that". Step 1 is to learn how to calculate the distortion in an amplifier (opamp) with feedback like you have. It has to do with excess loopgain. Also realize that the opamps will distort more when they have to deliver more output current.

Comment: If the target is a lock in amp, why are you concerned about noise?